# Select option queda con valor anterior al cargar con jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

selecciono un option por Javascript y al cambiar de celda no cambia de valor

```
$('#sProveedor option:contains("'Dato1'")').attr('selected', true);
document.ready = document.getElementById("sProveedor").value = 0;
```

Los selecciono por el valor de la tabla y por el valor por defecto para el nuevo

```
<select id="sProveedor" class="custom-select custom-select-sm" 
    required="">
     <option value="0" selected="">Seleccione una Opción</option>
     <option value="1">Dato1</option>
     <option value="2">Dato2</option>
     <option value="3">Dato3</option>
     <option value="4">Dato4</option>
     <option value="5">Dato5</option>
     <option value="6">Dato6</option>
     <option value="7">Dato7</option>
     <option value="8">Dato8</option>
     <option value="9">Dato9</option>
     <option value="10">Dato10</option>
     <option value="11">Dato11</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con _al cambiar de celda_? ¿Tienes varios _select_ iguales? Si es así, entonces el problema es que estás repitiendo ID y deben ser únicos.

Comment: son diferentes lo que pasa es que al seleccionar el select desde jquery por texto no al cambiar el valor no me cambia, queda con el valor anterior

Comment: De entrada `document.ready` no existe en Javascript, tal vez hay algo similar en jQuery. De cualquier forma, se necesitan más datos, edita la pregunta para agregar un ejemplo de tu código HTML y cómo intentas cambiar el valor con Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Usando el selector :contains() en este caso aplica a Dato1 y Dato11, por lo que queda seleccionado Dato11.

```
$('#sProveedor option:contains("Dato1")').attr('selected', true); // seleccionara Dato11
```

Pero luego esta la linea

```
document.getElementById("sProveedor").value = 0;
```

ejecutada luego de la primera invalida la seleccion y lo deja en la seleccion default (0). Usar `document.ready` para asignacion no tiene ningun efecto, puede que lo que buscas es ejecutar dicha linea durante el evento document.ready. Revisa el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // contains(Dato1) aplica a Dato1 y Dato11, por lo tanto el ultimo se queda seleccionado
  $('#sProveedor option:contains("Dato1")').attr('selected', true);
  
  // El mismo efecto, solo seleccionando por valor (jQuery)
  // $('#sProveedor').val(1);
  
  // El mismo efecto, solo estableciendo el valor (jaascript)
  // document.getElementById("sProveedor").value=1;
  
  // Esto vuelve el selector al valor original
  //document.getElementById("sProveedor").value = 0;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sProveedor" class="custom-select custom-select-sm" 
    required="">
     <option value="0" selected="">Seleccione una Opción</option>
     <option value="1">Dato1</option>
     <option value="2">Dato2</option>
     <option value="3">Dato3</option>
     <option value="4">Dato4</option>
     <option value="5">Dato5</option>
     <option value="6">Dato6</option>
     <option value="7">Dato7</option>
     <option value="8">Dato8</option>
     <option value="9">Dato9</option>
     <option value="10">Dato10</option>
     <option value="11">Dato11</option>
    </select>
```

Independiente de lo que desees lograr, siempre es mejor seleccionar opciones por su valor interno (atributo `value`) que por su contenido de texto.

Comment: En caso tal que no se pueda seleccionar el value sino el texto?, por que lo que hago es comparar el nombre que recojo de la una tabla y compararlo con el texto para haci tomar los dos valores tanto del value como del texto para una sentencia sql